# Azure Security between data centers

Tags: azure, security, azure-web-app-service

Can you confirm if the connection between a Azure Web App and Azure SQL DB needs to cross the internet if both the Azure Web App and Azure SQL DB would be hosted in the same Azure Region ( such as West US)? I understand that each region is covered by multiple data centers.

Is there some internal network connectivity within the data centers?

I know that we need to use Encrypt=True and TrustServerCertificate=False in the connection string to keep the data encrypted in transit.

Is there any documentation available on the network security between data centers within a region?

Comment: You can visit the Microsoft Trust Center and see if there is documentation there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The traffic between different data centers within a region is done over a private Microsoft network. In fact, even if both services were hosted in completely different regions, the connection does not go over the public Internet:

Source: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/how-microsoft-builds-its-fast-and-reliable-global-network/

> Azure traffic between our datacenters **stays on our network and** 
>   ***does not* flow over the Internet**. This includes all traffic between
>   Microsoft services anywhere in the world. For example, within Azure,
>   traffic between virtual machines, storage, and SQL communication
>   traverses only the Microsoft network, regardless of the source and
>   destination region. Intra-region VNet-to-VNet traffic, as well as
>   cross-region VNet-to-VNet traffic, stays on the Microsoft network.